# How to save the RatingBar values in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

I have used a RatingBar in my code, but I am having trouble saving the data. Additionally, I am encountering an issue where if I provide a rating for the first row, it is automatically taken as the rating for the seventh row.

I am using the following code:

```java
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        ratevalue=ratingBar.getRating();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to store rating bar values.

```
val preferences = getSharedPreferences("My_pref", MODE_PRIVATE)

@Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        preferences.edit().putFloat("Rating", rating).apply()
    }
```

to retrieve the value from shared preference, you can do like this.

```
val rating = preferences.getFloat("RATING", 0.0f)
```

Note: you will lose your rating values if you uninstall the app.